# Plotting points with factor data in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm trying to use `ggplotly()` with a scatterplot that has factors for both the x and y axes. However, `ggplotly` is doing something that I don't understand that dramatically changes the presentation of my data. Here's an example, but note that I intentionally made x and y factors and that they should not be considered numbers:

```
mydata = data.frame(x = factor(c(1:40)),
                    y = factor(sample(c(1:40), 40, replace = TRUE)),
                    count = sample(c(1:5), 40, replace = TRUE))

myplot = ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = count))
```

Using just `ggplot` it looks great:

[image]

However, when I use `ggplotly(myplot)` I get this, which is obviously very different:

[image]

My ultimate goal is to be able to mouseover each point and get the coordinates and the "count" variable. I'm open to alternative methods, but I'd also like to understand what's going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are still a lot of problems with plotly and ggplot2 working together. Sometime it works and sometime you have unexpected results (e.g. facet with legend). So sometime you have to go with the alternative; try this:

```
plot_ly(mydata, x = x, y = y,
        mode = "markers", size = count)
```

[image]